# HTML input update with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

We have a db :

```
ID    Name     Price
1   product1    200
2   product2    300
3   product3    400
```

and my form :

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" />
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="enter name product" />
<div id="result">display result form ajax</div>
<label>price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" readonly" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

js file :

```
// Start Ready
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });

});
```

when user search name product in search input (we send a ajax request to search.php and display products like that keyword)
search.php :

```
connection db and other code...
if(product) {
echo '<input type="radio" name="product" id="product" value="'.$result['name'].'" />'.$result['name'];
}
```

and user select that,Now how can update price input with the price of the product?

Comment: You could add the price in a `data` attribute -> `echo '<input type="radio" name="product" class="product" value="'.$result['name'].'" data-price="'.$result['price'].'" />'.$result['name'];`. Then in your js code, `$('ul#results').on('click', '.product', function(){ $('#price').val($(this).data('price')); });`. Note, each of your radio buttons would have `id="product"`, which creates invalid html, so I changed to `class="product"` to be used in the js -> `'.product'`

Comment: Thank you.it worked,one more question this way for fetch data is secure(my way)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by secure. Your code looks fine as is.  As long as you are properly sanitizing your data when you are searching your database you should be fine, as all you provided was `connection db and other code...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'search.php' should return json of price and html

```
{
    price: 200,
    html: "......"
}
```

and in success function, you can update price

```
success: function(json){
    $('#price').val(json.price);
    $("ul#results").html(json.html);
}
```